# How to uninstall msys2?

Tags: mingw, msys, msys2

How to uninstall [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/)? When I am trying to uninstall from "Programs and Features" I receive the error:

[image: error]

What to do? Just delete the msys2 folder?

*I am using Windows 8.1*

Comment: the prog has been unregistered already, and left some undeleted files/folders. that's probably the best thing to do

Comment: Please don't apply tags blindly, this is neither a C nor a C++ question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like MSYS2 has already been uninstalled and the entry is just a leftover. So confirm the question with Yes to get rid of the entry. If still present, you can of course delete the MSYS2 folder.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I had to go into the msys2 installation folder and rename maintenancetool.exe.new and maintenancetool.dat.new to maintenancetool.exe and maintenancetool.dat. Then the uninstall from the Control Panel went fine.

Answer (score 4):

I could not find MSYS in the Control Panel list of apps (on Windows 10). I just deleted the whole directory.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to restart computer in safe mode, to get rid of the folder.

1. Restart
2. Press **F8** on start up
3. choose *safe mode*
4. Delete it
5. restart again (for normal mode automatically)